# How to make kendo grid column not visible at first load

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this column settings in kendo grid

```
columnMenu: true,
columns: [
            {field: 'code'}, 
            {field: 'name'}                    
         ]
```

I want to make the name field is hidden at first. But user can make it visible from the column menu. How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its in the Kendo UI documentation.

```
 columnMenu: true,
 columns: [
{ hidden: true, field: "id" },
{ field: "name" }   ],
```

[Kendo UI Grid Columns Hidden](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.hidden)

Comment: i tried using hidden but the header column still showing. It worked fine when i hide/show from columnMenu.